# Affine semigroup generating a lattice

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, lattices, semigroups-and-monoids

This is a [cross-post from MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376145/affine-semigroup-generating-a-lattice)

Everything is assumed to be finite-dimensional. Let $S$ be a finitely generated affine semigroup (i.e. a subsemigroup of a lattice $N$ of a Euclidean space). Assume that $S$ generates $N$ as a group. Is it true that it contains all but a finite number of points in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} S\cap N?$

I believe the result should be known, however, I am not a specialist in convex geometry so book reference will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does prop 2.1.1b of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101116.pdf answer your question?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg No, unfortunately, I don't think so. If I understood everything correctly this statement describes the integral closure $\overline{S}$ of S. It is shown there that this semigroup coincides with $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} S\cap N,$ however it does not say anything about the set $\overline{S}\setminus S.$ Maybe it is a corollary of this proposition, but I don't see it now

Comment: It also says there are finitely many elements of $\overline S-S$ whose translates under $S$ give the normal closure. That should give you candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Write $\mathbf{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.)

What about the submonoid of $\mathbf{Z}^2$ generated by $\{(2,0),(3,0),(0,1)\}$? It equals $\mathbf{N}^2\smallsetminus (\{1\}\times\mathbf{N}$). So here the complement is infinite.

Comment: But are there examples which are normal (or integrally closed)?  In your example (1,0) is in the internal closure.  My vague memory is in the integrally closed case there are only finitely many missing points

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg where can I find the definition of normal and integrally closed in this context?

Comment: In the link I put in the comments above.  It's the obvious one that if some multiple of an element of the lattice belongs to S then the element belongs to S.